# Search items in array of objects that don't exist in another

Tags: php, search, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays that contain objects:

```
array $a (size=2)
    0 => 
       object(A)
       private '_id' => int 10
    1 => 
       object(A)
       private '_id' => int 11

array $b (size=1)
    0 => 
       object(B)
       private '_id' => int 10
```

I'm trying to find which item in array `$a` doesn't exist in array `$b`, which in this case is `$a[1]`. Looping both arrays can do this, but I would like a more effective way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation I pointed you to in the comment to the question clearly states:

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or
> greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be
> respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

The function you tried does something else, thus the result is unpredictable.

```
<?php
$a = [
  (object) [ '_id' => 10 ],
  (object) [ '_id' => 11 ],
];
$b = [
  (object) [ '_id' => 10 ],
];

var_dump(array_udiff($a, $b, function($l, $r) {
  return $l->_id > $r->_id ? 1 : $l->_id < $r->_id ? -1 : 0;
}));
```

The output is:

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
    ["_id"]=>
    int(11)
  }
}
```

A simplified version of the above example would be:

```
<?php
$a = [
  (object) [ '_id' => 10 ],
  (object) [ '_id' => 11 ],
];
$b = [
  (object) [ '_id' => 10 ],
];

var_dump(array_udiff($a, $b, function($l, $r) {
  return $l->_id - $r->_id;
}));
```